# Trouble with Google Tag Manager (GTM) New Event Listener Tags

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I'm very excited about GTM introducing the Event Listener tag options, and have used them with success on some websites. With several of my company's clients, however, I am having this strange issue.

I can see, using the debugger software that the Link Click Listener tag is firing, and I can see that the Record Event tag is firing. However the Events never show up in Analytics.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Even with the Link Click Listener and the Event Listener firing, you still need to add an additional Google Analytics tag OR Universal Analytics tag to utilize them within GTM. Remember, the only thing the listeners do is create new dataLayers for you to use.

To make events work in Analytics, add a NEW Google Analytics (or UA) tag to GTM.

Select the Track type as 'Event' 
Category: Whatever you'd like the category to be (you can use macros here as well)
Action: Whatever the action is, download, click, etc. (macros are helpful here too!)
Label: Whatever you'd like it to be.

The key here is how you setup the rules. Your {{event}} needs to utilize the dataLayer - gtm.click, then you need to specify an element you'd like to track.

For a fantastic tutorial, I recommend - http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/07/auto-event-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/